# How to show a loading spinner instead of the login button when the button has been clicked in next.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, routes, next.js

Hiho,

I'm just playing around with next.js and trying to create a little forum application.

After endless hours of googling around I have following question:

**How can I show a loading spinner instead of the login button when it has been clicked, until it's been resolved and then show the logout button?**

I managed to switch between Login and Logout (I just pass in the req.user prop into the navbar component and can conditionally show it).

But is there some kind of prop in the req object that indicates that it has not been resolved?

The next.js app uses express in the background.

So some routes are just Links to other pages and the login route is an actually API route.

This just authenticates with passport, and after success it redirects to "/".

I couldn't find any solution for this problem.

Here is a little preview of my navbar:

```
{user ? (
            <Link href="/api/auth/logout">
              <Button color="inherit">Logout</Button>
            </Link>
          ) : (
            <Link href="/api/auth/facebook">
              <Button color="inherit">Login</Button>
            </Link>
          )}
```

**How to add another conditional something like this:**

```
{isLoading ? (
            <p>Loading..</p>
          ) : user ? (
            <Link href="/api/auth/logout">
              <Button color="inherit">Logout</Button>
            </Link>
          ) : (
            <Link href="/api/auth/facebook">
              <Button color="inherit">Login</Button>
            </Link>
          )}
```

That would solve my last thing I'am stuck currently. I hope it's even possible, because I can imagine it's not an easy thing todo with SSR?

### What have I tried so far:

I managed to get at least a full page loading bar with the help of `next/router` and the npm package `NProgress`.

Set up like this (in the `_app.js`file)

```
Router.events.on("routeChangeStart", url => {
  console.log(`Loading: ${url}`);
  NProgress.start();
});
Router.events.on("routeChangeComplete", () => NProgress.done());
Router.events.on("routeChangeError", () => NProgress.done());
```

But that just gives me a full page loading indicator and I want just a little spinner while logging in.